# A way to get the table param

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table and I need to get the parameter of the cell I click on using jQuery.
How would I do this?

I need to get the 3rd row, 4th column. Here is what I have so far

```
var tr = $(this).parent();
for (var i = 0; i < tr.children().length; i++) {
    if (tr.children().get(i) == this) {
        var row = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't write everything in capital letters. It makes it kind of hard to read. Thank you! Also, you problem seems to be solvable by binding (or delegating) a click event handler to each cell. Have a look at jQuery's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
$('td').click(function(){
   var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var column = $(this).index()+1;
    var row = tr.index()+1;
    alert("you clicked row:"+row+" column:"+column);
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YA6WY/

Comment: Note that `index()` gets the position of the element relative to its parent.  If the table has several `<tbody>` or `<thead>` elements, `index()` might not return the required result.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `cellIndex` and `rowIndex` properties of the `<td>` and `<tr>` respectively.  Very simply:

```
$('table').delegate('td', 'click', function (evt) {
    var td = evt.target,
        row = td.parentNode.rowIndex;
        col = td.cellIndex;

    alert("Row: "+row+", Column: "+col); 
});
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/T4u93/**

Using `delegate()` to bind your event handler improves performance by adding a single event to the `<table>` element that catches all clicks on cells.  `event.target` gives us the element that generated the click (the `<td>` element, in this case).

- [rowIndex property, DOM Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-67347567) - w3.org
- [cellIndex property, DOM Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-80748363) - w3.org